# Google Places, Autofill is failing to autocomplete form components

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, autocomplete

This is probably a rookie error somewhere on my behalf, I just can't see where I'm going wrong. I've been playing around with the Google Places API and created a form, which I intend to be compatible with CF7 (Contact Form 7).

Side note "I'm still learning JS."

I haven't really dabbled with the API before so figured it's about time to start poking around, at-least at the basics. Which is all good fun, at least until you hit a brick wall. I'm hoping someone here could help shed some light on how the autocomplete populates form components, more specifically how form components are chosen and paired with the correct data. (If that makes sense.)

---

> -
>   **My Research**
>
> Initially I started with an auto complete base, of which I found [*here*](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/q8) had a little play and went on to study an example of which I found courtesy of Google, [*here*](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html). I studied a bit of the API docs [*here*](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Autocomplete) and eventually wound up tweaking my own version, [*here*](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/yndtp66n/3/) with a mix mash of code I found across the web.
>
> -
>   **My Goal**
>
> All I want to achieve is to populate the correct chosen data by the user in  the correct corresponding fields. However I could never get city to properly work for the UK.
>
> -
>   **My Issue**
>
> After heavily modifying the HTML and tweaking the JS the form components just started to refuse data (not display any data). Again as I mentioned earlier, it's probably my rookie mistake somewhere, but I can't see it.
>
> **[MY JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/yndtp66n/3/)**

```
// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}
// [END region_fillform]
```

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

$("#autocomplete").on('focus', function() {
  geolocate();
});

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'gb'
      } // Limit to UK Addresses Only.
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  var fullAddress = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
    if (addressType == "street_number") {
      fullAddress[0] = val;
    } else if (addressType == "route") {
      fullAddress[1] = val;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('fullAddr').value = fullAddress.join(" ");
  if (document.getElementById('fullAddr').value !== "") {
    document.getElementById('fullAddr').disabled = false;
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

initialize();
// [END region_geolocation]
```

```css
/* -- Default Override -- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  padding: .5em .4em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px !important;
}


/* -- Center Element -- */

.ele {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: solid 1.5px #4f4f4f;
  width: 750px;
  padding: 3%;
}


/* -- Form Styles -- */


/* Text Field Font */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
input[type='submit'] {
  padding: 1.2em 0;
  width: 97.8%;
  margin: .5em .5em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #9cc320;
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease .3s;
  border: solid 1.5px #9cc320;
}

input[type='submit']:hover {
  color: #4f4f4f;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: ease .3s;
  border: solid 1.5px #4f4f4f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='text'],
input[type='email'],
input[type='tel'],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #272727;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
}

.none {
  Display: none;
}


/* -- Form Layout -- */

.col {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em;
}

.col-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-half {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-third {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap" class="ele center">
  <div id="ctt-frm">
    <h2>
      Request your sample!
    </h2>
    <div class="col col-half">
      <label aria-label="First Name Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name"><input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="FIRST NAME *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-half">
      <label aria-label="Last Name Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap last-name"><input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="LAST NAME *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-half">
      <label aria-label="Email Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="EMAIL *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-half">
      <label aria-label="Telephone Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-tel"><input type="tel" name="your-tel" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="TELEPHONE *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-full">
      <label aria-label="Autocomplete Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-auto"><input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="your-auto" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="PLEASE ENTER YOUR ADDRESS" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-full none">
      <input type="text" id="street_number" name="street-number" value="" size="40" class="none" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="000" Disabled />
      <input type="text" id="route" name="route" value="" size="40" class="none" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Route" Disabled />
      <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="" size="40" class="none" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="country" Disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-full">
      <label aria-label="Address Line 1 Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-add1"><input type="text" id="fullAddr" name="your-add1" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="ADDRESS LINE 1 *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-full">
      <label aria-label="Address Line 2 Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-add2"><input type="text" name="your-add2" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="ADDRESS LINE 2" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-third">
      <label aria-label="City Town Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-city"><input type="text" id="locality" name="your-city" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="CITY / TOWN *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-third">
      <label aria-label="County Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-county"><input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_2" name="your-county" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="COUNTY *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-third">
      <label aria-label="Postal Code Field"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-postcode"><input type="text" id="postal_code" name="your-postcode" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="POSTAL CODE *" /></span></label>
    </div>
    <p class="col col-full">
      <label aria-label="Message Area"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap message-body"><textarea name="message-body" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="MESSAGE * ( Please list any additional information here. )"></textarea></span></label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any assistance I can get with this, many thanks in advance.

Regards,
- B

---

**EDIT : 27 SEP 17**

After the worlds largest headache, I finally got it working; I learned that it would'nt place the values if one or two of the fields were missing. More specifically the Lat and Lon.

The solution was to add these fields and disable them, also making them 'display:none;'. My code may not be the cleanest but it may be a stepping stone for others.

Here is the complete working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/yndtp66n/5/).

I would still like to see how the js should be structured with the correct ISO for the UK. If anyone could help with that I would be greatful.

Regards, 
- B.